# iOs downloading .ics file is adding a .txt extension

Tags: javascript, ios, icalendar

I have an .ics generator which works fine on desktop but in mobile safari when downloading the .ics file a .txt extension is added to it(calendar.ics.txt).  I know it must have something to do with the data:text/calendar setting but I can't figure it out.  Any hints?:

```
export const download = (filename, text) => {
  const element = document.createElement("a");
  element.setAttribute(
    "href",
    "data:text/calendar;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(text)
  );
  element.setAttribute("download", filename);
  element.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
  element.style.display = "none";
  element.click();
};
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I'd be keen to know this too!